# Can I use python3 with IDA 7.0?

Tags: ida, x86, idapython

Got IDA Pro 7.0 (I can't update at the moment),
I'm currently unable to use idapython.

I have python3.8 installed on my machine and nothing else (I dont want any collisions).

How can I use make Idapython work without having **only** 2.7 installed.

Comment: AFAIK IDA 7.4 is the first version that has Python3 support. If you can't update it that or a newer version and need idapython you have to install Python2.7.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_python3.shtml) on the IDA website, you need IDA Pro 7.4 to use Python 3.

Regarding version 7.4, the site says:

> When IDA 7.4 is released, it will come with precompiled builds of
> IDAPython not only for Python 2.7, but also for a variety of Python
> 3.x versions (we haven't settled for a set of versions yet.) By default, IDA 7.4 will install IDAPython for Python 2.7, but users will
> have the opportunity to pick an alternative build that runs against
> their Python 3.x installation.

I have found [this porting guide](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_python3_porting_guide.shtml) very useful. Using Python 3 with IDA 7.4 is great, and the new API is cleaner in many ways.