# How to change IDA to use Python 3.7 and not Python 2.7: "do not have the x86_64 architecture"

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I have IDA 6.95, Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.
Currently when I start IDA it uses Python 2.7:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 
IDAPython v1.7.0 final (serial 0) (c) The IDAPython Team <idapython@googlegroups.com>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wanted to change it to 3.7.
I tried to do it with `idapyswitch.exe` but failed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA 6.95>idapyswitch.exe --force-path "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python3.dll"
Cannot determine python library version for "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python3.dll": DLLs in directory "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32" do not have the x86_64 architecture
```

How can I change it, I don't understand what is the problem with the architecture of the files?

Comment: Python 3 support came with ida 7.4 I thought

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/25682/3013

Comment: make sure you install python3 64bit. (32bit only would not work)